# text orientation on excel(individual cell) in python

Tags: python, xlwt

I am trying to write some data on excel file, and want to keep first row text orientation as 90 degree.

```
style = xlwt.easyxf('font: bold 0, color black, underline 0,height 250; alignment: horizontal left')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example how you can do this:

```
import xlwt

style = xlwt.easyxf('align: rotation 90')

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Test')
worksheet.write(0, 0, label='Formatted value', style=style)
workbook.save('test.xls')
```

You can use `rota` or `rotation` keyword.

FYI, here's the [function](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/xlwt/Style.py#L503) being called under the hood.

Hope that helps.